# do we have org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.InputDialog with combobox

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

Similar to org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.InputDialog, i want to show a combo box, loaded with some values, to the user. User should be able to select from the list of values or type in their own value. I cannot use a parent/composit. I want it to work similar to InputDialog, but with a combo box instead of just a text box (as in Inputdialog). Please suggest any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such dialog built-in, just inherit from [`org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.html) and create your own.